# Find pandas worksheet position by taking its name from the user's input (input label in TKinter)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, xlwings

I have an input window in my Tkinter frame where the user inputs the name of the worksheet e.g. 'Sheet 1', and I have created a function to delete the rows in this sheet.

I want to use this function to iterate through all the worksheets using the given worksheet name.

I have accomplished that for now by inputting the position of the sheet, e.g. `0` or `1`. But I tried with the proper name and I converted it as a string, but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Below is my code that is working now giving the number of the worksheet.

```
def delete_rows(self):
    # Input the number of the worksheet of the excel file
    self.j = int(self.entry_5.get()) 

    # The user input the first row he wants to start deleting
    self.row_rage_to_delete = self.entry_1.get() 

    #The user input the last row he wants to finish deleting
    self.row_rage_to_delete2 = self.entry_2.get()

    # Start iterating (looping) through the worksheets of the excel file
    while self.j<len(self.wb.sheets):
        self.sht = self.wb.sheets[self.j]
        self.sht.range(str(self.row_rage_to_delete) + ':' + \
          str(self.row_rage_to_delete2)).api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
        self.j += 1
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Warning', 'The rows have been deleted from all sheets')
```